# Проблемa с locust. response.failure('status code is' + str(response.status_code)) - ошибка, якобы я передаю два аргумента

Tags: python, python-3.x, нагрузочное-тестирование, locust

```
    @task(3)
def few_cell_fill_table(self):
    if self.token:
        headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.token}
        with self.client.post(self.table_end_pont, json=UserBehavior.modify_req(one_times=False),
                              name="few_change_cell",
                              headers=headers) as response:
            if response.status_code != 200:
                response.failure('status code is' + str(response.status_code))
```

На этой строке постоянно получаю ошибку

```
        response.failure('status code is' + str(response.status_code))
TypeError: _failure() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Что за приколы, думаю, решил посмотреть ку ведёт failure

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может у меня не тот failure, подскажите что делать?

Comment: Первый аргумент - self, второй - тот, что написано в скобках.

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну вот и как текст ошибки теперь туда текст ошибки отправить(

Comment: куда "туда"?...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
def few_cell_fill_table(self):
    if self.token:
        headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.token}
        with self.client.post(self.table_end_pont, json=UserBehavior.modify_req(one_times=False),
                              name="few_change_cell",
                              headers=headers) as response:
            if response.status_code != 200:
                status_code = 'status code is ' + str(response.status_code)
                response.failure(status_code)
```

Comment: к сожалению не тот случай(